# how to mock parent::xxx method

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

Is there a way?

```
class AAA extends BBB {
    public function ccc()
    {
        parent::ccc();
    }
}
```

I want to check parent ccc method 1 time called

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing a class that calls parent::function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246594/testing-a-class-that-calls-parentfunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static calls can't be mocked and are usually a bad smell.

http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

That said, [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) does have some wizzardry to allow you to test them:

http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html

But you really shouldn't be using static methods.